# copy object in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js, pie-chart

I draw a diagram, after collecting the parameters in a loop ($.each). The string is assembled, but does not work like that

```
var PieData = company;
```

And when I copy the line and paste directly it works fine.

```
var PieData = [{value: 14, color: '#2bea4f', highlight:'#2bea4f', label: 'Cts group'},{value: 4, color: '#411820', highlight:'#411820', label: 'СБЕРГРУЗ'},{value: 18, color: '#3b53a4', highlight:'#3b53a4', label: 'Фаворит Экспресс'},{value: 3, color: '#698bb4', highlight:'#698bb4', label: 'Бечехан'},];
```

How to make it work?

Source code below

```
    //-------------
//- PIE CHART -
//-------------
// Get context with jQuery - using jQuery's .get() method.

var pieChartCanvas = $('#pieChart').get(0).getContext('2d')
var pieChart       = new Chart(pieChartCanvas)

var company = "[";

$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
    var col = randColor();
    company += "{value: " + value.countShip + ", color: '" + col + "', highlight:'" + col + "', label: '" + value.name + "'},";
});

company += "]";

//var PieData = company;

var PieData        = [{value: 14, color: '#2bea4f', highlight:'#2bea4f', label: 'Cts group'},{value: 4, color: '#411820', highlight:'#411820', label: 'СБЕРГРУЗ'},{value: 18, color: '#3b53a4', highlight:'#3b53a4', label: 'Фаворит Экспресс'},{value: 3, color: '#698bb4', highlight:'#698bb4', label: 'Бечехан'},];

var pieOptions     = {
    //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
    segmentShowStroke    : true,
    //String - The colour of each segment stroke
    segmentStrokeColor   : '#fff',
    //Number - The width of each segment stroke
    segmentStrokeWidth   : 2,
    //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
    percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts
    //Number - Amount of animation steps
    animationSteps       : 100,
    //String - Animation easing effect
    animationEasing      : 'easeOutBounce',
    //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
    animateRotate        : true,
    //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
    animateScale         : false,
    //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
    responsive           : true,
    // Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
    maintainAspectRatio  : true,
    //String - A legend template
    legendTemplate       : '<ul class="<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'
}
//Create pie or douhnut chart
// You can switch between pie and douhnut using the method below.
pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, though from a brief look into your code I see that 
you tried to use a String as a JSON object.

Try replacing

```
var PieData = company;
```

with

```
var PieData = JSON.parse(company);
```

Comment: Tried, but not working "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data"

Comment: Try building your JSON without using strings. For example,
company = [];
obj.map( element => {
  company.push({value: element.exampleProperty})
})

Comment: Thank bro! obj.map() did not use it. Rebuilt the line var company and JSON.parse(company). Where were problems with the structure JSON.